# Nvidia Jetson TX2 vs Nvidia GTX 1060 TI

Tags: gpu, nvidia

I am in the process of buying a GPU for production deploy. I am thinking of whether to buy an off the shelf gpu like the Nvidia GTX 1060 TI or spend more money and buy the Jetson TX2... space is not a constraint for us. But with some googling around i couldn't get a comparison on both.

How should i go about comparing these two gpus? Price wise GTX 1060 is much cheaper than Jetson TX2.

Answer (score 2):

The specs of they two are quite accessible online, so I won't copy and paste them here. 
[Specs of TX2](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems-dev-kits-modules/) and [Specs of GTX 1060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1060/)

In short, TX2 is a good choice, if:

- you are power consumption sensitive;
- you are computational power insensitive;
- the data throughput is not too heavy;
- you have no problem with developing in Ubuntu environment;

Otherwise, GTX1060 is the one you should go for, if:

- you already have a PC as host device;
- this PC has PCI slots and sufficient power supply;
- you may develop in Windows environment;
- the data throughput is heavy;
- the computational requirement is tough;

In my opinion, one should always consider from a system's point of view, finding the optimal point for the banlance amongst computational power, power consumption, software integration, I/O speed, and so on.